# Table with same rows different sizes in different Databases (Azure SQL) - Why and what changed after truncating and re-populating

Tags: azure-sql-database

I had a scenario where, the table size was different between two different DB's. A daily ETL ingests data in both these DB's.

**Question 1** : Why there is a huge difference in the data sizes between two tables when they have same no.of rows

**Question 2** : To check if ETL is causing the issue, i have truncated the STG DB and re-populated it. Then the size drastically came down. What happened in the background?

The table size difference is below between prod and staging

```
                     Reserved           data                index           Unused
            PROD    GB  63.81627655 =   34.31835938     +   25.10404968  +  4.393867493
    STG (Before)    GB  121.465538  =   63.31293488     +   33.34213257  +  24.81047058                 
    STG (After)     GB  46.60236359 =   24.79945374     +   20.24600983  +  1.556900024
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about how you populated things, it is hard to say for sure.  However, Azure SQL DB contains a feature called Accelerated Database Recovery (ADR) which keeps prior page versions for a time in the database to facilitate faster recovery on failovers (which reduces downtime on failovers since recovery has to happen to reconcile the log and the database file in a database system).  There is a background job to clean up old pages once they are no longer needed.

There are also background tasks that clean up other things.  They do this to make you have faster mainline operations in your database by pushing work from your application into the background.  So, it is likely one or more of these that are causing the differences you see.